# MySQL Workbench acesso negado

Tags: mysql, linux

Boa tarde, estou tendo problemas no mysql workbench, está dando permissão negada, porém quando entro pelo terminal como superusuario eu consigo acesso.

(imagem acesso negado no workbench)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(imagem acesso pelo terminal como root)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**(codigo do my.cnf)**

```
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.

#
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

Comment: Qual distro vc está usando? como está a porta 3306 na firewall?

Comment: Estou utilizando Debian 9 e a porta está aberta para o mysql

Comment: Possíveis problemas:
Porta fexada 3306
Mysql não está configurado para receber conexões externas, pelo terminal vc consegue porque esta fazendo uma conexão local.
Verifique o arquivo de configuração do mysql e libere para acesso externo.

Comment: @AlessandroSchneider qual arquivo configuro? my.cnf , debian.cnf, mysql.cnf, ou mariadb.cnf? porque nenhum deles tem especificado port.

Comment: para liberar acesso externo basta comentar a linha
**bind-address = 127.0.0.1** no seu arquivo my.cnf

Comment: @AlessandroSchneider meu arquivo não tem está linha, vou editar  a publicação com os codigos do my.cnf

Comment: Você pode editar esse arquivo que postou, ou pode fazer um include por ele, especificando um novo arquivo de configuração.
Você pode ter maiores detalhes em https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/configuring-mariadb-with-mycnf/

Answer (score 1):

use o mysql db e o comando abaixo.

```
UPDATE user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password' WHERE user = 'root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Esta é a comunidade portuguesa do StackOverflow. Traduza a sua resposta para português.